# Pass json To A foreach View cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm working on cakephp, make an http client where the driver is like this

```
public function index()
{
    $http = new Client();
    $response = $http->get('http://localhost/paginaws/articles/index.json');
    $json = $response->json;
    $valor = $response->body;

    $this->set(compact(['valor']));
}
```

and what I want is to pass it to a view that is going to be a table. I know I have to use a `foreach` but it does not show me anything. When doing a `var_dump` shows me that it is an object type.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is written in Spanish. Questions written in Spanish should be asked on the [**Spanish StackOverflow**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/). Por favor, haga su pregunta [**aquí**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/) en su lugar.